# Get parent node dimensions in svelte

Tags: html, css, svelte

I'm trying to use Svelte and it's my first time so sorry for maybe the stupid question. I read the Svelte documentation but I'm stuck with a simple problem.

Basically, I would like to get the parent dimensions (width and height) of a component.

Example:

```
<div>
  <MyNode />
</div>
```

Inside `MyNode` I would like to have the dimensions of the parent `div`. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount, tick } from 'svelte'

  let w = 0
  let h = 0
  console.log({ w, h })

  onMount(async () => {
    console.log('on mount')
    console.log({ w, h })
    // await tick()
  })
</script>

<main>
  <div class="flex w-screen h-screen">
    <div class="white w-150 min-w-150 h-full">side menu</div>

    <div
      class="bg-ligthGrey flex-grow h-full border border-orange-500"
      bind:clientWidth={w}
      bind:clientHeight={h}
    >
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

this is what I get:

[image]

This is printed only the first time (of course, it is inside the onMount), if I resize the window, nothing change.
I need to have `w` and `h` always updated. How can I do?

Comment: Generally one should not need sizes that much, are you sure this could not be done in CSS? (On StackOverflow people tend to ask about an issue they are stuck with instead of asking how to do what they actually want to achieve. A fix to a bad solution still gives you a bad solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make the log reactive `$: console.log({ w, h })` it will execute whenever `w` or `h` changes

To have the dimensions of the parent div inside the component I would pass them as a prop [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c8725be04fd54f2cad9daf218e3d49e8?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import MyNode from './MyNode.svelte'
    
    let w, h
</script>

<div bind:clientWidth={w} bind:clientHeight={h}>
    <MyNode parentWidth={w} parentHeight={h}/>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        background: lightblue;
    }
</style>
```

###### MyNode.svelte

```
<script>
    export let parentWidth, parentHeight    
</script>

MyNode - parentWidth: {parentWidth} - parentHeight: {parentHeight}
```

(Notice that `parentWidth` and `parentHeight` will initially be `undefined` inside the component - depending on what you plan to do based on them, this should be handled)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in other frameworks the code between `script` tags is only executed *once*, during initialization. This explains why you see the `{w: 0, h: 0 }` as those are values at that time.

To indicate that a piece of code should run again, you have to explicetely mark it as 'reactive'. In your case this would be:

```js
$: console.log({w, h});
```

You can do the tutorial to learn more about this: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-assignments